# Android Jelly bean camera return null URI

Tags: java, android, android-camera, uri

I'm trying to use the camera to take pictures in my app, and then crop the taken images.

Everything is working for the recent versions for Android, but not for Android Kitkat 4.4.2.

the Camera returns a null URI.

get the URI onActivityReslult :

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            picUri = data.getData();
            Intent i = new Intent(PublierActivity.this, CropActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Uri", picUri);
            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_CODE);

        }
```

Here is how I call the camera intent :

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_CODE);
                }
```

is there any way to make an exception for oldest versions for android to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it would appear that you are trying to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. In that case, there should **never** be a `Uri` — `data.getData()` should always be returning `null`. If a camera app happens to return a `Uri`, that *may* be the image, but since `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not documented to return a `Uri`, you have no way of knowing what that `Uri` is for.

If you are using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, you know where the image should be stored, because you told the camera app where to store it. Note that some camera apps are buggy and fail to honor `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, putting the image wherever they want.

If you are not using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, then you will get a thumbnail back in the `"data"` extra.

Also, please bear in mind that this has nothing to do with Android OS version, and everything to do with the camera app that the user chooses to use. There are thousands of Android device models. These ship with dozens, if not hundreds, of different camera apps pre-installed. The user might also elect to install a third-party camera app. Any of those could be handling your request.